# Is it possible to switch from applied maths to pure maths?

Tags: phd, graduate-school, mathematics, masters

I've found a couple of questions of the type "is it possible to go from pure to applied" so I was wondering if anyone knows for the opposite direction.

Say you are an *applied mathematician* with an *applied math's masters* (say, a total of 6-7 years of applied maths in total, including undergrad: you'd know functional analysis (as well as convex analysis, Fourier analysis, complex analysis, etc),  general topology, the very basics of abstract algebra, a lot of optimization, probability (markov, etc) and PDE). Is it possible to then switch to pure mathematics? Can you get into a masters program on pure math's? Do you have to take a masters on pure mathematics before going for a PhD in this case? How likely is it for one such person to get accepted on a grad school program for pure maths?

Answer (score 3):

As always, the correct answer depends on the country you are in. In the US, for example, Mathematics Ph.D. programs would accept someone with a background from an area that uses Mathematics such as Engineering. Also, many programs do not make a difference between applied and pure mathematics. In India, you might have more problems because career paths are less permeable.

If you already have an MS in Applied Mathematics, and want to get into an MS in Pure Mathematics, most programs (in the US) would not hesitate to take you provided you can provide letter of references. It is your money that you are going to spend on a somewhat useless degree. ("Useless" because I cannot think of examples for jobs that you can do only with an MS in pure Mathematics.)

Chances for admittance will depend on finances (if you are a foreign student, tuition at state universities will be higher, and any support would be more expensive; the availability of support), your test scores, your prior research experiences, how your interests match up with the departments, your references, ... In general, pure Mathematics is not the most-sought out Ph.D. program.

Comment: *I cannot think of examples for jobs that you can do only with an MS in pure Mathematics* --- In the U.S. this is a fairly standard requirement for a community college teacher of mathematics (sometimes just 18 semesters of graduate math, and a masters degree in anything), although for this career path the OP already has an appropriate degree, since "pure mathematics" and "applied mathematics" are probably not going to differ for the requirement. Incidentally, other than possibly algebra, the OP probably already has more background than most U.S. "pure math" masters-only degree holders.